# mod-rewrite when index.php is in the URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to rewrite http://example.com/admin/pages/index.php to http://example.com/index.php?admin=admin&cid=pages.

It works for http://example.com/admin/pages (which I also want), but not for http://example.com/admin/pages/index.php.

How is this accomplished?

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
# If the request is for a valid directory, file, or link, don't do anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1

# If you add this first rule to support views, be sure to remove the QSA flag from the second rule (maybe not required since the first rule has the L flag)
#replace admin/cid with index.php?admin=admin&cid=cid
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?admin=$1&cid=$2 [L,QSA]
#replace mypage with index.php?admin=mypage
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?admin=$1 [L,QSA]
```

EDIT

Random changes shows that this might be correct.

```
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index.php/?$ index.php?admin=$1&cid=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?admin=$1&cid=$2 [L,QSA]
    #replace mypage with index.php?admin=mypage
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index.php/?$ index.php?admin=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?admin=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your first rule that is skipping all files & directories from rules.

Replace your rules with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

#remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [L,R=302]

# If you add this first rule to support views, be sure to remove the QSA flag from the second rule (maybe not required since the first rule has the L flag)
#replace admin/cid with index.php?admin=admin&cid=cid
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/?|/index\.php)$ index.php?admin=$1&cid=$2 [L,QSA]

#replace mypage with index.php?admin=mypage
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?admin=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  Could you explain `RewriteRule (?:^|/)index\.php$ - [L,NC]`?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks anubhava,  It now appears to work. Could you explain what `(?:/?|/index\.php)` is doing?  Also, `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]` says to always remove `index.php` so it may be written back, correct?

Comment: I have removed earlier `RewriteRule (?:^|/)index\.php$ - [L,NC]` and `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]` basically stops rewriting if current URI is `/index.php`